# NodeJS, DiscordJS command arguments split by {}

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Quick question

If I am making a command like the following

```
!add {gamename}{gamedescription}{gamestatus}
```

How would I know that each argument is inside of the `{}`

I know the actual command is my first arg

```
 let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");
 switch(args[0]) {
    case 'status':
```

PREFIX being the '!'

Just not sure how I set argument 1 has the first string inside of the first `{}` and so on.

Answer (score 4):

This regular expression will do the trick. Test it out below.

```js
const regex = /{(.+?)}/g;
const string = '!add {game}{game description}{game status}';

const args = [];

let match;
while (match = regex.exec(string)) args.push(match[1]);

console.log(args);
```

**Explanation:**
To see how the regex works and what each character does, check it out [here](https://regex101.com/r/kM9zY5/19). About the `while` loop, it iterates through each match from the regex and pushes the string from the first capturing group into the arguments array.

**Small, but worthy note:**
`.` does not match line breaks, so arguments split up into multiple lines within a message will not be included. To prevent this, you could replace any new line character with a space before using the regex.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to capture substrings in a pattern.

```
const message = {
  content: '!add {gamename}{gamedescription}{gamestatus}'
};

const matches = message.content.match(/^!([a-zA-Z]+) {([a-zA-Z]+)}{([a-zA-Z]+)}{([a-zA-Z]+)}/);
if (matches) {
  console.log(matches[1]); // add
  console.log(matches[2]); // gamename
  console.log(matches[3]); // gamedescription
  console.log(matches[4]); // gamestatus
}
```

When the string matches the pattern, the `matches` object has substrings surrounded by `()` in `matches[1]`, `matches[2]`, `matches[3]` and `matches[4]`. `matches[0]` has the entire matched string (`!add {gamename}{gamedescription}{gamestatus}` in this case).

Comment: So it would work even if gamedescription is a lot of text?

Comment: If it's a text with spaces and symbols, the subpattern `{([a-zA-Z]+)}` needs to be adjusted according to which characters you want to allow in it. How long can it be? Can it have line breaks?

Comment: it's a description of a game server... What was shown above was the command format. This is how the command could be.

Comment: !add {RektServers}{This is the best damn server in the freaking world!}{Running}

Comment: That's why I am asking if there is a way to split by {} so it knows the arguments are inside the {} <---curly brackets

Comment: OK, if you just want to split, how about something like: `const a = args[1]; const items = a.slice(a.indexOf('{') + 1, a.lastIndexOf('}')).split('}{')` ?